# "2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query" but NOT TIMEOUT and NOT LARGE PACKET

Tags: mysql, segmentation-fault

I'm getting this lost connection error, but all the help I can find on-line seems to be around either timeout or large packet problems.  I'm pretty sure neither of those apply in my case because it is failing instantly (sub 1 second) so, that pretty well rules out a timeout problem.  And, it's failing on simple queries against a small sample data set, so I can't imagine how packet size would be a factor.  Based on some of my playing around, it seems like it's some internal issue because sometimes if I drop and re-create a table or view that will get the error to go away (but not always).  It does seem to be only certain tables in my model that are having this problem.  How do I debug this problem?  I can't figure out what is actually causing this.

I'm running MySQL version 5.5.29 on my MacBook Pro (10.10.5) via MAMP (2.1.2).
I'm hitting it via both PHP code also running locally, and also via the SequelPro tool (v1.1, build 4499).  When I am able to identify the offending query in my PHP code it tends to also give the same error via SequelPro.

The error I am getting is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server
>   during query

I checked out the error log and I see that mysqld is seg-faulting.

```
151031 10:07:05 [ERROR] Found index case_id_name whose column info does not match that of MySQL.
151031 10:07:05 [ERROR] Build InnoDB index translation table for Table ./diyevict_db/data_value failed
151031 10:07:05 [ERROR] Index case_id_name of diyevict_db/data_value has 2 columns unique inside InnoDB, but MySQL is asking statistics for 3 columns. Have you mixed up .frm files from different installations? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html

17:09:48 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=3
max_threads=151
thread_count=3
connection_count=3
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338482 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1018ebc00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 10dffbeb8 thread_stack 0x40000
0   mysqld                              0x000000010027c38c my_print_stacktrace + 44
1   mysqld                              0x0000000100021be4 handle_fatal_signal + 692
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8f315f1a _sigtramp + 26
3   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
4   mysqld                              0x0000000100326ac1 row_update_for_mysql + 385
5   mysqld                              0x000000010030988e _ZN11ha_innobase10update_rowEPKhPh + 1134
6   mysqld                              0x000000010002491e _ZN7handler13ha_update_rowEPKhPh + 142
7   mysqld                              0x00000001001db207 _Z12mysql_updateP3THDP10TABLE_LISTR4ListI4ItemES6_PS4_jP8st_ordery15enum_duplicatesbPySB_ + 3735
8   mysqld                              0x00000001001673ed _Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD + 8061
9   mysqld                              0x000000010016bb66 _Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state + 294
10  mysqld                              0x000000010016cc8e _Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj + 1710
11  mysqld                              0x000000010016db77 _Z10do_commandP3THD + 231
12  mysqld                              0x000000010020d611 _Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD + 353
13  mysqld                              0x000000010020d6c9 handle_one_connection + 73
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff98bda05a _pthread_body + 131
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff98bd9fd7 _pthread_body + 0
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff98bd73ed thread_start + 13

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1018d2c10): UPDATE `data_value` SET `deleted` = 1, `update_version` = update_version + 1 WHERE `id` = '9'
Connection ID (thread ID): 5
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Looks like the problem was a corruption between the table and the index.  I fixed it by dropping and re-creating the table.  Not sure what caused it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, enable mysql's [error log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-log.html), and perhaps even its general query log (just for debugging purposes, turn it off afterwards). These 2 logs will tell you what went wrong and what may have caused it.

You can also try to search mysql's bugs based on your sql or can even raise a bug yourself and see what the developers come back. Be careful: you have to be very specific and must be able to provide steps to repeat the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I've added the error log output to my post.  It's seg-faulting!  Trying to run check programs to see if a table is corrupted, but haven't found any errors yet.

Comment: Giving you the answer credit since I found the issue in the error log after a little digging.